# Is libpthread needed if the pthread API is in libc

Tags: c, pthreads, glibc, libc

Looking at the output of `readelf -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` on my Ubuntu 22.04 box, I see (what looks to be) the entire pthread API contained in the `.text` section.

As a sanity check, I successfully compiled and ran

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <pthread.h>

static void *
func(void *args) {
    return args;
}

int main() {
    int ret;
    pthread_t thread;

    ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, NULL);
    if ( ret != 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return ret;
    }
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

without using `-pthread`.

Given all of this, is there any purpose to libpthread on my computer other than providing support for older applications which expect it to be there?

Comment: Think about the floating point math functions, while they are part of the standard C library, they are still put in a separate library. If the specifications, manual pages or references say that you need to link with a specific library, then you probably should link with that library.

Comment: But `sqrt` isn't actually in libc.so.6.  `pthread_create` et al are.

Comment: That's not guaranteed or specified. It happens to be true for your specific implementation. Also note that there *are* POSIX thread functions which will *not* be in `libc` on a normal Linux (for example) system.

Comment: *I successfully compiled and ran*  Did you?  How do you know that code ran successfully?  You're not checking any return values, for example, so from what you've posted the separate thread may very well not have been created at all.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, what I meant was I didn't run into any linking errors.

Comment: Missing linking errors doesn't mean the code works correct when executed. So did you run _the application_ or just the linker? I remember some glibc that had stub functions for some pthread functions and returned error.

Comment: @KamilCuk, see the updated version of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is libpthread needed if the pthread API is in libc

No.

> is there any purpose to libpthread on my computer **other than** providing support for older applications which expect it to be there?

No.

See https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/12/17/why-glibc-234-removed-libpthread . Since then libpthread is an empty library.

Comment: Prior to glibc 2.34, linking with libpthread is absolutely necessary. There's still a lot of glibc < 2.34 extant.

Comment: Note also that there is a difference between passing the `-pthread` option to `gcc` and explicitly linking `libpthread`.  The former is what programs *should* be doing, and it may have more (or different) effects than causing `libpthread` to be linked.  In particular, note that the GCC manual lists it both as a preprocessor option and a link option.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yup.  I made sure to do things the right way.